# unsupported operand type(s) for +=: 'bool' and 'str', однако я сделал приведение типов

Tags: python, python-3.x

Такой вопрос. Выдаёт ошибку о разных типах, однако приведение типов я сделал. Не могу разобраться, в чем проблема. Сообщатся о проблеме в строке `buf += str(randbrend(x))`

Текст ошибки:

```
File "C:\Users\Danil\PycharmProjects\untitled\BDLab4.py", line 115, in Add
    buf += str(randbrend(x))
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +=: 'bool' and 'str'
```

```
add = ("INSERT CARS(Brend, Model, Number, Weight)"
       "VALUES('")
buf = add
str(buf)
x = randint(0, 5)
buf += str(randbrend(x))
buf += "', '"
x = randint(0, 5)
buf += str(randmodel(x))
buf += "', '"
x = randint(0, 5)
buf += str(randnumber(x))
buf += "', "
x = randint(2, 6)
buf += str(x)
buf += ");"
```

Comment: Код из вопроса не вызывает такую ошибку: https://ideone.com/7WxXr8

Comment: Эта ошибка из другого кода, в этом код нет bool-переменных.

Answer (score 0):

Вы не преобразовали `buf`. Надо вот так:

```
add = ("INSERT CARS(Brend, Model, Number, Weight)"
       "VALUES('")
buf = str(add)
```

Comment: В данном коде add изначально строка, нет смысла ее еще раз преобразовывать в строку. Скорее всего пропущен какой-то код, который автор вопроса почему-то посчитал несущественным.